# Silverlight implement value converter to comboBox

Tags: silverlight, xaml, combobox, valueconverter

I have the following scenario

1- A combobox in xaml

```
<ComboBox 
x:Name="PublishableCbo" Width="150" IsEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" 
SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Published, Mode=TwoWay}"
Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="0">
<ComboBox.Items>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="All"  IsSelected="True" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Yes"  />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="No"  />
</ComboBox.Items>
```

2- In a model class, I defined a property and bind to the selectedvalue in combobox

```
 public bool Published
    {
      get
      {
        return _published;
      }
      set
      {
        _published = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Published");
      }
    }
```

I know I have to implement a converter, but don't know exactly how. What I want is when a select Yes/No, in the model get a True/false value, when "all" is selected, to get null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to assign `null` to the `Published` property, you would have to change its type to [Nullable< bool >](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (you can write `bool?` in C#).

```
public bool? Published
{
    ...
}
```

The Converter could be implemented so that it converts from `string` to `bool` and vice versa, perhaps like shown below. Note that the converter uses `bool`, not `bool?` since the value is passed to and from the converter as `object`, and hence boxed anyway.

```
public class YesNoAllConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object result = "All";

        if (value is bool)
        {
            result = (bool)value ? "Yes" : "No";
        }

        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        object result = null;

        switch ((string)value)
        {
            case "Yes":
                result = true;
                break;
            case "No":
                result = false;
                break;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

To enable the use of this converter, you have to change your ComboBox item type to `string`, and bind to the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property, not SelectedValue.

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Published, Mode=TwoWay,
                         Converter={StaticResource YesNoAllConverter}}">
    <sys:String>All</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Yes</sys:String>
    <sys:String>No</sys:String>
</ComboBox>
```

where `sys` is the following xml namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! works perfect! How can I set the "All" value is selected by default when the page load? Now I don't have the IsSelected attribute